Docker, nginx, Rails, Puma. Static files are not served but should be
I tried to migrate from Passenger to Puma in a Rails 5.2 project. This is a Docker setup using nginx to redirect from http to https and forward the requests to the Rails container. I had this set up perfectly working with Passenger. Since Puma is the preferred server by the Rails community, I tried to replace Passenger with Puma. After some hiccups, nginx and Puma found each other and the content was served, but every asset and static file was not found, I always got "301: Permanently moved". The identical configuration had worked with Passenger though. (I think this could have been fixed if I had told Rails to serve static files, but I did not want to do this for performance reasons.)
Putting one of the URLs in question into wget gave me the following:
wget http://myserver.de/assets/application-606786f053f1b452d1089f9f5e4741add1d55c6d89223168b844dd9f21740aee.css
URL transformed to HTTPS due to an HSTS policy
--2024-07-08 16:21:27--  https://myserver.de/assets/application-606786f053f1b452d1089f9f5e4741add1d55c6d89223168b844dd9f21740aee.css
Auflösen des Hostnamens myserver.de (myserver.de)… xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Verbindungsaufbau zu myserver.de (myserver.de)|xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx|:443 … verbunden.
HTTP-Anforderung gesendet, auf Antwort wird gewartet … 301 Moved Permanently
Platz: https://myserver.de/404.html [folgend]
--2024-07-08 16:21:27--  https://myserver.de/404.html
Wiederverwendung der bestehenden Verbindung zu myserver.de:443.
HTTP-Anforderung gesendet, auf Antwort wird gewartet … 301 Moved Permanently
Platz: https://myserver.de/404.html [folgend]
--2024-07-08 16:21:27--  https://myserver.de/404.html
Wiederverwendung der bestehenden Verbindung zu myserver.de:443.
HTTP-Anforderung gesendet, auf Antwort wird gewartet … 301 Moved Permanently
.
.
.
.

Translation:

Auflösen des Hostnamens = Resolving host name
Verbindungsaufbau zu = connecting to
HTTP-Anforderung gesendet, auf Antwort wird gewartet = Http request sent, waiting for response
Wiederverwendung der bestehenden Verbindung zu = reuse of existing connection to

Can anybody tell me what is wrong?
EDIT: Here are all configs:
# NGINX config:

server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  mydomain.de;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/my.access.log  main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/my.error_log  warn;
    
    proxy_connect_timeout  900;
    proxy_send_timeout    900;
    proxy_read_timeout    900;
    send_timeout      900;
    # for issuing certificates
    #
    #location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    #     root /var/www/certbot;
    #}

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    #     proxy_pass http://app:3000/;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    http2 on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.de/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.de/privkey.pem;
    server_name mydomain.de;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;

    client_max_body_size 20M;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/my.access.log  main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/my.error_log  warn;

    proxy_connect_timeout  900;
    proxy_send_timeout    900;
    proxy_read_timeout    900;
    send_timeout      900;

    # for re-issuing certificates
    #
    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
         root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://app_net:3001/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}

DOCKER-COMPOSE.yml
services:
  proxy:
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginx_proxy
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      mynetwork:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.80.10
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
    volumes:
    - /root/volumes/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
    - /root/volumes/nginx/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
    - /root/volumes/nginx/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot


  app:
    image: myrepo/myapp
    depends_on:
    - db
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    volumes:
      source: /root/volumes/nginx/certbot/conf
      target: /myhomedir/config/certs
    environment:
    ...

# DOCKER_ENTRYPOINT.sh
#! /usr/bin/env bash

cron
crontab /etc/cron.d/my_crontab
touch ./log/cron.log

sleep 5 && bundle exec rake db:migrate
bundle exec rake tmp:clear
bundle exec puma -b 'ssl://0.0.0.0:3001?key=/myhomedir/config/certs/live/mydomain.de/privkey.pem&cert=/myhomedir/config/certs/live/mydomain.de/fullchain.pem'

... anything else needed?

We run Puma in development and Passenger in production without issues.  That being said, might want to add your configuration file to the question.

@dbugger I also run Puma in development and Passenger in production. However, I want to run Puma in production as I'm told it's so much better than Passenger at dealing with heavy traffic. (Besides, why use two different servers when one would suffice?)

Why change a working setup because of something you were told? :) And you stil l haven't added your configuration.

@dbugger Simplify an unneccessarily complex setup, get better performance, follow recommendations, reduce differences in setup between development and production.
